# Is it possible to deny the non-compliant resource in Azure Policy

Tags: azure, azure-policy

For example, I have 2 initiatives following Azure compliance offerings. 1 is ISO, a set of policies; 1 is PCI, another a set of policies. Both initiatives include lots of build-in policies. Some resources are non-compliant due to the applied policies. But the development still passed somehow (probably because the effect type specified in the policies is `Audit` or `AuditIfNotExists`?)

However, I want to prevent development if there is any resource is non-compliant due to the ISO and PCI policies. Is there any way to do so?

Something like, if I can create a new policy with the definition that *if* the resource is `non-compliant` due to the policies applied in ISO or PCI initiatives, *then* give **effect type** `deny`. Then, add this policy into to both initiatives. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you will have to customize the effect type to be deny. In a deny policy, it will deny those new resources that are non-compliant, while marking old resources as non-compliant.

Another solution is to parameterize the effect type so that you can assign the effect type as needed. If you decide to do this, be sure to have a default value